# click is being recognized as a double click jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm writing because I need to solve this problem, when I click on my div, it doesnt work, works but only if I double click that. Same with hiding div, I need to click 2 times to hide it.

```
 <div>
  <div class="parent"></div>
  <div class="child">list to show</div>
```

```
 showAndHide(){
        $('.Parent').click(() => {
            $('.Child').toggle();
            console.log("asdasd");
        })
    },
```

And on the console.log the line "asdasd" is being incrementet for 1 after I click on my parent Div,

Comment: Can you please show a working example of the issue, including all relevant HTML and JS. My guess is you're calling `showAndHide()` when the element is clicked too, so your event handlers are nested

Comment: the projects is on vue.js and its huge, this is my html code
<div>
<div class="Parent">
 X
</div>
<div class="child">
And some items here
</div>
</div>

Comment: Maybe because your first call to `showAndHide` will add event for _future_ clicks and does not executes event, and only second click has event binded?

Comment: and im calling this on my vuejs by @click="showAndHide"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm calling this on my vuejs by `@click="showAndHide"`

This is the issue. You have nested your event handlers so the toggle happens N+1 times for each additional click.

To fix this remove the `@click="showAndHide"` attribute and attach the event handler only *once* using the unobtrusive jQuery handler:

```
$('.Parent').click(() => {
  $('.Child').toggle();
  console.log("asdasd");
});
```

Alternatively, retain the `@click` attribute and remove the jQuery event handler:

```
showAndHide() {
  $('.Child').toggle();
},
```

Comment: Yes its working , thanks man , and sorry if i was not good at representing my problem. <3 <3